# Creating a round robin MySQL connection manager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, ninject

### Background

I am working on an e-commerce website, my web server is written in ASP.NET MVC (C#, EF6) and I am using 3 instances of MySQL DB. These DBs are in a cluster ([Galera Cluster)](https://galeracluster.com/products/) and they are automatically replicated.

The problem that I want to solve is load balancing the requests among these 3 instances of MySQL... according to MySQL documentation this can be easily achieved by using a multi-host `connectionString`, like:

```
Server=host1, host2, host3; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

Unfortunately this does not work for Connector/NET (there are multiple open bugs: [81650](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81650), [88962](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88962), [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274136/connectionstring-for-connecting-3-master-nodes-to-mysql))

### My solution

I have tried to implement a simple round robin load balancer for my application.

The aim is to split the multi-host `connectionString` into multiple single-host `connectionString`s, for example the above `connectionString` would be converted to:

```
Server=host1; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword; 
Server=host2; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword; 
Server=host3; Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

The program would use a round robin algorithm to pick one of these `connectionString`s. If one of the connections fails, I would ignore that connection for 5 mins and then it would be retried again.

### The code

`MySQLConnectionManager.cs` is going to split each of the multi-host `connectionString`s into several single-host `connectionString`s, note that I have 2 `connectionString`s, one for `DataDb` and one for `LogDb`:

```
<add name="DataDb" connectionString="Server=1.2.3.10, 1.2.3.11; Database=db1; Uid=root; Pwd=..." providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<add name="LogDb" connectionString="Server=1.2.3.10, 1.2.3.11; Database=db2; Uid=root; Pwd=..." providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

It also has the LoadBalancer instance for each of of the `connectionString`s.

*MySQLConnectionManager.cs*

```
public static class MySQLConnectionManager
{
    private const string _server = "server";

    // in this case, I want one load balancer for DataDb and one for LogDb
    private static Dictionary<string, DbLoadBalancer> _dbLoadBalancers = new Dictionary<string, DbLoadBalancer>();

    static MySQLConnectionManager()
    {
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings multiHostConnectionString in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            DbConnectionStringBuilder dbConnectionStringBuilder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
            var singleHostConnectionStrings = SplitMultiHostConnectionString(multiHostConnectionString.ConnectionString);

            if (singleHostConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                _dbLoadBalancers.Add(multiHostConnectionString.Name, new DbLoadBalancer(singleHostConnectionStrings));
            }
        }
    }

    public static DbConnection GetDbConnection(string connectionStringName)
    {
        if (_dbLoadBalancers.ContainsKey(connectionStringName))
        {
            return _dbLoadBalancers[connectionStringName].GetConnection();
        }

        throw new Exception($"Could not find any `connectionString` with name = {connectionStringName}");
    }

    private static List<string> SplitMultiHostConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        List<string> singleHostConnectionString = new List<string>();

        DbConnectionStringBuilder dbConnectionStringBuilder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString
        };

        if (dbConnectionStringBuilder.ContainsKey(_server))
        {
            string allServers = dbConnectionStringBuilder[_server] as string;
            string[] allServersArray = allServers.Split(',');

            foreach (string server in allServersArray)
            {
                DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.ConnectionString = dbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
                builder[_server] = server.Trim();
                singleHostConnectionString.Add(builder.ConnectionString);
            }
        }

        return singleHostConnectionString;
    }
}
```

*LoadBalancedConnectionString.cs*

```
public class LoadBalancedConnectionString
{
    public LoadBalancedConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        LastTimeConnectionWasUsed = DateTime.Now;
        IsDbAlive = true;
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastTimeConnectionWasUsed { get; set; }

    public bool IsDbAlive { get; set; }
}
```

DbLoadBalancer.cs

```
public class DbLoadBalancer
{
    private List<LoadBalancedConnectionString> _loadBalancedConnectionStrings;
    private int _timeToIgnoreFailedDbInMin = 5;
    private LoadBalancerLogger _logger = null;

    public DbLoadBalancer(List<string> connectionStrings, string logPath = "")
    {
        _loadBalancedConnectionStrings = new List<LoadBalancedConnectionString>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logPath))
        {
            _logger = new LoadBalancerLogger(logPath);
        }

        foreach (string connectionString in connectionStrings)
        {
            _loadBalancedConnectionStrings.Add(new LoadBalancedConnectionString(connectionString));
        }
    }

    public DbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        LoadBalancedConnectionString lastUsedConnectionString = null;
        string message = string.Empty;
        string lastException = string.Empty;

        while (_loadBalancedConnectionStrings.Any(c => c.IsDbAlive == true))
        {
            try
            {
                lastUsedConnectionString = _loadBalancedConnectionStrings.OrderBy(c => c.LastTimeConnectionWasUsed).FirstOrDefault();
                MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(lastUsedConnectionString.ConnectionString);
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                lastUsedConnectionString.LastTimeConnectionWasUsed = DateTime.Now;
                lastUsedConnectionString.IsDbAlive = true;
                _logger.Write($"{DateTime.Now}: using: {lastUsedConnectionString.ConnectionString}");
                return mySqlConnection;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lastUsedConnectionString.LastTimeConnectionWasUsed = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_timeToIgnoreFailedDbInMin);    // don't use this connection for the next 5 mins
                lastUsedConnectionString.IsDbAlive = false;
                message += $"{DateTime.Now}: Failed to connect to DB using: {lastUsedConnectionString.ConnectionString}\n";
                lastException = ex.Message;
                _logger.Write($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: Fail to connect to: {lastUsedConnectionString.ConnectionString}, marking this connection dead for {_timeToIgnoreFailedDbInMin} min");
            }
        }

        _logger.Write($"{DateTime.Now}: All connections are dead.");
        throw new Exception($"Cannot connect to any of te DB instances. {message}\n Exception: {lastException}");
    }
}
```

This is working as expected...

I am using ASP.NET Identity and Ninject for DI, I had to do the following modification to `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // this is how the constructor used to be 
    // public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DataDb")
    // {
    // }

    public ApplicationDbContext() : 
        base(MySQLConnectionManager.GetDbConnection("DataDb"), true/*contextOwnsConnection*/)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am passing true for `contextOwnsConnection`, I believe (for EF6) this means the connection should be terminated once `DbContext` is disposed... this seems the logical choice for me, but would be great to get some feedback on this... **I am worried to leave open connections around... or close the connections to soon** (so far it has passed my initial tests)

And this is the `Ninject` code, since this is a web project, I am using `InRequestScope()` for all dependencies.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<ICategoryRepository>().To<CategoryRepository>().InRequestScope();
    ...
}
```

---

Before trying to reinvent the wheel, I contacted Oracle and pointed out that this issue has been open since 2016... then I tried to use AWS Network Load Balancer but I did not manage to get it working [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/995677/using-a-aws-network-load-balancer-for-mysql-cluster)... on the Galera documentation, I see many solutions use HAProxy, but this means I would have to set up 2 new servers (to have a fault tolerant HAProxy)... which seems too much investment in hardware... I also looked into using a DNS record with multiple IPs to split the load among different DBs... this apraoch seems a bit controversial... also I was also not sure if AWS CloudFront caching would cause any issues, so decided not to use it.

*Note: I have put the final code in [Github](https://github.com/HoomanBahreini/MySQLConnectionManagerForNet), in case anyone wants to use it.*

---

### Update

This issue has been fixed in Connector/NET 8.0.19, see: https://insidemysql.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Aliveness issue

As it is, your code does not perform the task you expect it to, because the LoadBalancer never reinstates "dead" connection pools.
Notice that you only ever set `LoadBalancedString.IsDbAlive` to `true` in the constructor *or* if another connection is alive **after** the timeout expired.

If ever all the servers managed in the `DbLoadBalancer` are offline, the balancer never recovers.

This can be remediated by adjusting the lookup you perform.
Instead of using a while-loop that is never executed if all connections are dead, you may want to iterate over all connection strings regardless of their `IsDbAlive` status:

```
public DbConnection GetConnection()
{
    foreach (var candidate in _loadBalancedConnectionStrings.OrderBy(c => c.LastTimeConnectionWasUsed))
    {
        if (!candidate.IsDbAlive && DateTime.Compare(c.LastTimeConnectionWasUsed, DateTime.Now) > 0) 
        {
        // connection is not alive, no retry yet -> skip connection
            continue;
        }
        // try-catch goes here
    }
}
```

Sidenote: `candidate` here takes the place of `lastUsedConnectionString`. I like my name better ;)

#### Typing Effort

I notice that for the vast majority of your variable declarations you explicitly declare the type of the variable.
For quite a while now C# supports strictly typed left-hand side type inference (implemented with the `var` keyword).

It's idiomatic (and common) for C# code to use `var` on the left hand side for all declarations that allow it.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out the all "dead" scenario, you have saved me a lot of debugging time... I agree, candidate is a much better name.

Answer (score 4):

**MySQLConnectionManager**

`DbConnection GetDbConnection()` and `List<string> SplitMultiHostConnectionString()`

Whenever you also need the value for a given key of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you **shouldn't use** `ContainsKey()` together with the `Item` getter **but**  you should use [`TryGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Internally these three methods are calling the [`FindEntry()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) method to check wether a given key exists. So calling this method only once through the `TryGetValue()` method should be the way to go.

**DbLoadBalancer**

`DbConnection GetConnection()`

Don't compare a `bool` against `true` or `false` just use the
bool as the condition.

Don't use

```
while (_loadBalancedConnectionStrings.Any(c => c.IsDbAlive == true))
```

but

```
while (_loadBalancedConnectionStrings.Any(c => c.IsDbAlive))
```

Because you don't change neither `_loadBalancedConnectionStrings` nor `_logger` you should make these variables `readonly` to prevent accidentally changes.

I think for the constructor you didn't want

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logPath))
{
    _logger = new LoadBalancerLogger(logPath);
}
```

but something different. I can't tell excatly what because it wouldn't make sense either to revert the condition. Right now if you pass a value other than `""` any method call of `_logger` will result in a `NullReferenceException`. By reverting the condition (which would make more sense) but passing `""` would result in the same exception.

Passing a `List<string> connectionStrings` to the constructor restricts you to only use a `List<string>`. Hence if you e.g have `string[]` or an `IEnumerable<string>` you would need to change this into a `List<string>` but because you are only enumerating the items you should better use just an `IEnumerable<string>`.

---

**General**

- Declare variables as near to their usage as possible.
- Your naming is good. Especially you name your things in respect to the .NET Naming Guidlines.

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether I should set `contextOwnsConnection` flag or not... Ninject is managing the dependencies, so it is possible that the same instance of `DbConext` is used multiple times within once request... But I cannot think of a scenario where the same connection is shred among multiple `DbContext`s.. that's why I set the flag to true...

Comment: All good advises, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the testability of your code by:

- Refactoring SplitMultiHostConnectionString() into it's own class
- Passing in the connection strings instead of accessing ConfigurationManager (thus removing the dependency on ConfigurationManager)
- This will make your class no longer static, but you can make it a singleton via the DI framework
- moving the logic around mySqlConnection.Open(); into it's own function, since that call makes the entire thing untestable

Quality issues:

- Do not throw or catch System.Exception. In your case in particular, you need to be able to distinguish if any error is retryable. For example, you'll fail ungracefully if the connection string is malformed. Better: Review what exceptions are going to be thrown by the called code.
- Code is not thread safe. You also update LastTimeConnectionWasUsed only after opening the connection, giving other threads an large window to use that same connection. Better: Use ConcurrentQueue
- I would not set LastTimeConnectionWasUsed five minutes into the future. This will make the code harder to maintain and debug. Better: Put broken connections into a standby list instead of implicitly bringing them back into rotation.

I think it's a tricky thing to get 100% right. I'd load balance with an external load balancer like [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The LB code has 3 classes, non of them bigger than 70 lines... I tried to keep it small and simple... following your recommendation, I would need to add extra classes and logic to it, which could make the code quite complex... this is just my opinion, but I don't want to violate KISS and YAGNI principles.